# How to show that a bijection doesn't exist?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let A be a set and P(A) be the power set of A. Show that there doesn't exist a bijection from A to P(A).

Hint: Use contradiction, suppose g is a bijection and define B = {a E A | a E g(a)}. Then B has a pre-image... Is this the pre-image of B in B?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $g: A \rightarrow \mathscr{P}(A)$ is a bijection. Define $B = \{a \in A: a \notin g(A)\}$. Then $B \in \mathscr{P}(A)$, so there is some $a_0 \in A$ such that $g(a_0) = B$, as $g$ is surjective by assumption. But then $a_0 \in g(a_0)$ iff $a_0 \in B$ iff $a_0 \notin g(a_0) $, which is a contradiction. I don't think the argument works if you'd define $B$ in your suggested way. 
This proof is due to Cantor, the founding father of set theory, BTW.